# CSS: Make the color of the button be lighter in the middle

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm new to web design.

I have a button of green color. How can I make the color be lighter in the inside and darker in the edges. (Not talking about the outside shadow)

Here's an image

[image]

Notice the effect of the inside color, it becomes lighter as it approaches the middle of it. What effect do they use for this? Almost as if it's 3D in a way.
Thanks

Comment: inset box shadow or gradient

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve with a box-shadow (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow). Here is an example using a semi-transparent black box-shadow.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.btn {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 300px;
  line-height: 50px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #00B000;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 25px rgba(0,0,0,.25)
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">
  Add to Cart
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this by using a gradient. This is how I'd do it, personally.

You can use a site such as [Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

You can visually create the gradient on the site, and it'll spit out the CSS code ready for you to paste:

```
http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#176300+0,408e00+52,176300+100 */
```

background: #176300; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #176300 0%, #408e00 52%, #176300 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #176300 0%,#408e00 52%,#176300 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #176300 0%,#408e00 52%,#176300 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#176300', endColorstr='#176300',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try a radial-gradient:

```
    button {
    padding: 10px 40px;
    background-image: radial-gradient(#00cc44, #009933);
    font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";
    color:#fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
} 
<button type="button">ADD TO CART</button>
```